# Keywords separation in database using a comma

Tags: c#

I am using asp.net & c# and I want to create a text box where the user enters keywords separated by a comma and it enters each keyword in a separate row.

for example, if the user enters: " java, c#"
It will be saved in the database as

```
1 java 
2 C#
```

I need your guidance and your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourvariable.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(d =>
{
    [insert d.Trim() to DB]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the keywords you can

```
var keywords = inputText.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList();
```

and then you can save that list of strings the your database.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution would be to use client side  control which can convert words to tags for user and to send List in model to server 
You can check [select2 taging](https://select2.org/tagging) also there is lot of similar gui contollors.

Then in your model (post) you can accept List not just string.